# правильное создание бэкап сайта

Tags: резервное-копирование

Добрый день, я новичок. Мне часто приходится делать доработки на сайте или какие либо изменения. И чтобы себя обезопасить я постоянно копирую файлы которые редактирую на свой компьютер.

Хостинги постоянно разные как и движки, нужно какое то универсальное решение.

У меня вопрос, как правильно делать бэкап сайта перед началом работы с сайтом , чтобы обезопасить себя?

желательно какую то легковесную копию, без картинок.  Я немного пользовался git , но еще не знаю можно ли делать такой бекап через него.

Буду очень благодарен за информацию, возможно какие то статьи , ссылки, мануалы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git или SVN это самые правильные инструменты для контроля версиями.
Вы не только сохраняете файлы,Но и в любой момент может откатится до какого commit a вы хотите.
Пользуйтесь этими инструментами.На сегодняшний день это очень востребовано.
Но это только для файловой системы.Для баз данных вы должны в ручную зделать backup и так db.sql хранить на Git вместе с остальными файлами

Comment: Можете поделиться каким то мануалом?    какой вопрос у меня остался. у меня десяток сайтов в поддержке. мне каждый из них нужно забекапить. как я могу это сделать гитом? купить приватный профиль. А дальше как? тоесть мне нужно добавлять какие то инструменты или файлы на фтп? расскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @mydls1, на bitbucket бесплатные приватные репозитории, в отличии от github

Comment: Спасибо за инфу. Может есть информация или видео о том как делать слепки с фтп?

Comment: esli u vas est ssh dostup k serveru to vi takje mojete postavit na servere Git ,rabotat na localk,delat commit na Git a potom cherez ssh ispolzuya git  sdelat pull ,eto toje samoe chto esli bi vi v ruchnuyu zalilibi fayli na srver.
Dlya nachala izuchite GIT , posle etogo ya uveren na mnogie voprosi sami otpodudt

Comment: esli ponravilsya otvet to pojalusta postavte ocenku najav na strlochku vverx vozle otveta,ili najav na galochku,spasibo
eto vam ssilka po izucheniyu GIT https://habrahabr.ru/post/125799/